# How to use coredata in library project while generating SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data, static-libraries

I am trying to develop SDK ,I need handle coredata in library project finally will add into my app  will update in my application also  ,I am followed this [working-with-core-data-in-a-static-library](https://bharathnagarajrao.wordpress.com/2014/02/14/working-with-core-data-in-a-static-library/) .

**But I am facing some issues are :**

> - Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'.
> - Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Cannot create an NSPersistentStoreCoordinator with a nil model'. Thanks.

Comment: did you create a bundle which the link says and add it to your application project?

Comment: Yes Created  added to my application .If you forward any sample application that is more helpful for me Thanks.

Comment: Not enough detail. Somehow you're passing a nil value for the persistent store URL, but then you probably knew that. There's no generic reason for that to happen, so you need to provide more information about what exactly is happening when you try to create the persistent store.

Comment: I am developing SDk for iOS .In my SDK code,I need to get data from Parse SDK(third party library) store in local database(Coredata) of SDK.Thanks